# Is "Ego, <name>" the incipit of any classical memoir?

Tags: literature-request

The title of Robert Graves's 1934 novel *I, Claudius* sounds like it could plausibly have been the incipit of Claudius's real autobiography.  Claudius did, in fact, write an autobiography in eight volumes, though as I understand it, it has been lost.  But did any other historical figure from Ancient Rome produce a memoir that we know began with the word *Ego*, followed by their name?  That is, could Graves have possibly patterned his title after the title or incipit of a surviving ancient text?

Comment: Graves stated that Claudius wrote the two books through him (Graves). It's hard to believe but considering the detail and the powerful pro-Claudius narrative (politician; statesman; judge; historian; war-leader) one wonders.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure whether this counts as classical, but the fictitious autobiography of St Clement of Rome (“pseudo-Clementine Recognitions”) in the Latin translation by Rufinus begins with the words “Ego Clemens in urbe Roma natus” etc. Rufinus died in 410.